# Redirect shows ip instead of url

Tags: wordpress, url, ip, mask, directadmin

I know this question is placed many times, except my situation is different and couldn't find the right answer.

I have a wordpress installed on a path bij direct admin on 123.456.11.11/path.
My domain is registered by a other company and i did a redirect to the ip/path. That was working fine but i had to turn the mask function off because otherwise it wouldn't open a secure https location.

Now the site and the https location is working fine except that it's showing the IP instead of the URL. I wanted to add an A record by the domain hosting but i can't set an A record to a path.

The question is how can i show the url without the mask function and the Wordpress installed on a path?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that when running the wordpress installation wizard, the url you were using had the I.P address rather than the domain name, i.e `http://123.456.11.11/path` instead of `http://yourdomain.com/path`

During the installation process Wordpress saves the url used in the options table and uses it as the base url for future operations e.g. when you create a new post or page, or use the `site_url()` function to generate a link.

If this is the case, assuming you retained the default table prefix, you will have to edit the `wp_options` table (using phpmyadmin) and update `siteurl` and `home` from the ip based url to the domain name url.

Don't forget to include the path.

This means, using your example:

change the url from

```
http://123.456.11.11/path
```

to

```
http://yourdomain.com/path
```

If you had created posts and pages you will have to update their paths also. They are found in the `wp_posts` table.

Comment: Thanks for the fast response. I wil try this and come back with the result